# How to execute all the bash cmds one after the other even after failure occurs?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Here is the set of cmds in a `.sh` file to run at once; but, whenever a failure occurs in a step, the following cmds (steps) are not run.

```
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=AE DOCKER=false > ./reports/a.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=BH DOCKER=false > ./reports/b.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=QA DOCKER=false > ./reports/c.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=EG DOCKER=false > ./reports/d.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=LB DOCKER=false > ./reports/e.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=ES DOCKER=false > ./reports/f.log &&
rake mobile BROWSER=chrome COUNTRY=MA DOCKER=false > ./reports/g.log &&
```

Comment: Those lines should probably have a single `&`, which means detach as a background process, assuming that is what you want. The double, `&&`, is  a boolean AND test which does exactly what you don't want, which is to only execute the rhs command if the lhs command returned success.

Comment: but it usually triggers all the cmds immediately (parallel); I want to execute the steps one by one @ccarton need to wait for the previous step to finish

Comment: Then just get rid of the ampersands entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just separate with **;** instead of **&&**

EDIT: the **;** is really not needed (@the Tin Man)

Comment: You don't need to replace the `&&`s, do you?

Comment: `;` isn't needed. Remove the `&&` that currently end each line.